# Creating a graph constant dynamically

Tags: java

I need some help with creating a constant 
I have created a constant using static values as follows

```
private static final Graph.Edge[] GRAPH = {
  new Graph.Edge("a", "b", 7),
  new Graph.Edge("a", "c", 9),
  new Graph.Edge("a", "f", 14),
  new Graph.Edge("b", "c", 10),
  new Graph.Edge("b", "d", 15),
};
```

Graph Edge method is

```
public static class Edge {
    public final String v1, v2;
    public final int dist;
    public Edge(String v1, String v2, int dist) {
        this.v1 = v1;
        this.v2 = v2;
        this.dist = dist;
    }
}
```

How can i create the graph constant dynamically when provided data in an array ?

Comment: How are you going to provide the array? A constant created dynamically sounds like a contradiction. Maybe you just want a static variable not a constant.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you want GRAPH to be a constant, you can do this:

```
//do not assign value yet
private static final Graph.Edge[] GRAPH;

...

//static initializer block
static{
  //get a reference to the array you are talking about
  //You can do whatever you like with tempGraph, not necessarily in one line
  Graph.Edge[] tempGraph = {
    new Graph.Edge("a", "b", 7),
    new Graph.Edge("a", "c", 9),
    new Graph.Edge("a", "f", 14),
    new Graph.Edge("b", "c", 10),
    new Graph.Edge("b", "d", 15),
  };
  //you set GRAPH to be the previously built tempGraph 
  //this is what you can do only one time, only in static initalizer block
  GRAPH = tempGraph;
}
```